# Does PostgresSQL 16 support Active Active replication ? I am using the free version

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to configure Active Active replication between 2 Postgres servers. Is it available in the free latest version of Postgres?

Comment: PostgreSQL is always free, no matter what version you download.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

If you create a subscription with `origin = none` from PostgreSQL v16 on, then you can replicate the same table in both directions without getting into an infinite loop, but there is no support for conflict resolution: if you perform conflicting operations concurrently on both servers, replication will hang, and you have to clean up the mess manually.